# Craft Commerce Orders - Customise Sources

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce2

In the backend, under orders, is there any way to create a custom source based on a particular product that is purchased?

My customers will only ever be purchasing 1 product as there is no basket, there will only ever be 1 product available per month, but I'd like to be able to have separate lists to see how many orders have been placed on a particular product.

I've looked at order criteria and tried to filter by a product ID but it didn't seem to work?

Thanks.